# Turn off grey box when mousedown in Mobile Safari

Tags: safari, webkit, mobile-safari

On Mobile Safari, when you click on an element it gets a grey box around it between mousedown and mouseup.

How do you turn this off?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was looking for the answer as well, and found it in the jQTouch CSS source code. Just add this to your definitions: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` Note that the box shows up for anything with a "click" or "touchend" listener (I think), so for best results, toss it under `body { }`